# cytoscape js event when all elements rendered?

Tags: cytoscape.js

Is there an event emitted when cy.add(elements) is finished?  It appears there's an event fired for each element added, but I don't see an event when all elements have been added and rendered.

ex:

```
  var elements = [ { data: {id: 'n1'} }, { data: {id: 'n2'} }, { data: {id: 'n3'} }, ];
  cy.add(elements);
  cy.on('add',function(evt){
     console.log('Element Added')
  })
```

The log will run three times.

Comment: What is the actual effect you are trying to achieve?

Comment: My app has other processes that need to run once all elements have been added.  Updates mostly to tables and graphs.  This happens frequently since I use a headless graph to perform calculations and transfer the results to the visible graph,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** I refactored per your comment. This will allow you to detect and do something after each "batch" is added.

I started with an example from the cytoscape.js website and heavily edited it for this answer.

You will probably want to run the snippet full screen to see the canvas and the console at the same time.

```js
// For generating new IDs
var ids = [];

function newId() {
    if (!ids.length) {
        ids.push('1');
    } else {
        var id = '' + (parseInt(ids[ids.length - 1]) + 1);
        ids.push(id);
    }
    return ids[ids.length - 1];
}

// Draw for first time
var cy = cytoscape({

    container: document.getElementById('cy'),
    elements: [], // don't add elements initially
    style: [{
        selector: 'node',
        style: {
            'background-color': '#666',
            'label': 'data(id)',
            'width': 10,
            'height': 10
        }
    }, {
        selector: 'edge',
        style: {
            'width': 3,
            'line-color': '#ccc',
            'target-arrow-color': '#ccc',
            'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
        }
    }],
    layout: {
        name: 'grid',
        rows: 1
    }
});

var batchTotal = 0;
var totalAdded = 0;

// Start listening to events
cy.on('add', function(evt) {
    console.log('event heard: add');
    if (totalAdded < batchTotal) {
        totalAdded++;
    }
    console.log('totalAdded/batchTotal: ', totalAdded + '/' + batchTotal);
    if (totalAdded == batchTotal) {
        console.log('entire batch added');
        // do whatever you want!
    }
});

var xStart = 10;
var x = xStart;
var y = 40;
var xInc = 20;
var yInc = 30;
var max = 200;
var addTotal = 2;

// For adding new elements
function add() {
    // let's build multiple elements to add at once
    var elements = [];
    var id;
    var el;
    for (var i = 0; i < addTotal; i++) {
        id = newId();
        el = {
            data: {
                id: id
            },
            position: {
                x: x,
                y: y
            }
        };
        elements.push(el);
        if (x <= max) {
            x += xInc;
        } else {
            x = xStart;
            y += yInc;
        }
    }
    addElements(elements);
}

// wrap the cy.add() method
// so we can inject our total counter
function addElements (elements) {
    if (!Array.isArray(elements)) elements = [elements]; // convert to array
    // this would be useful in a more robust app where
    // addTotal may change
    batchTotal = elements.length;
    // reset
    totalAdded = 0;
    cy.add(elements);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>CytoscapeJS Example</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/2.7.0/cytoscape.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    #cy {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="add()">Add</button>
  <p>Click add and watch the console. Look for the <strong>entire batch added</strong> message.</p>
  <div id="cy"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think this will work.  Any rendering triggers this event, not just the adding of entities.  Running layouts also triggers onRender.

Comment: @JLF Please look at the updated answer. I believe this is what you are after.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  I was afraid I'd have to result to some sort of 'event' counting measure.  I was really hoping I just missed the 'all elements have been added' event, but I guess that was wishful thinking.  Again, thanks for the snippet.

Comment: While this may work, it's a bit roundabout.  Adding elements is synchronous, so all this extra work is unnecessary.  Rendering is asynchronous, and you haven't detected that here.  I don't think you ever need to know when something is drawn, because you always have synchronous access to the public API anyway...